# What is the opposite of mutually exclusive?

Tags: probability

When $A \cap B = \emptyset$, $A$ and $B$ are said to be mutually exclusive.

Is there a term to describe events that must occur together or sets that perfectly overlap?  i.e., $P(A, B) = A$, $A \cap B = A$

Comment: This is not really the definition of mutually exclusive.  Two events $A, B$ are _mutually exclusive_ if they are disjoint, i.e., $A \cap B = \phi$.  Indeed if $A, B$ are mutually exclusive then $P[A\cap B] = P[\phi] =0$, but the converse is not true.

Comment: If $A \subseteq B$ then $P[A \cap B] = P[A]$.  More generally, $P[A\cap B] = P[A]$ if and only if $P[A \cap B^c]=0$.

Comment: I've rephrased it in terms of set theory, but I don't exactly see why the converse isn't true.  If the probability that they occur together is 0, then they are disjoint, are they not?

Comment: @ConleyOwens: The intersection might be a set that is not empty but has probability 0.

Comment: Michael seems to consider the continous case, where $P(A)=0$ does not imply that $A$ is  impossible. In the discrete case, $P(A)=0$ implies that $A$ is impossible.

Comment: A simple example is when $X$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.  Define $A = \{X \in [0,1/2]\}$ and $B=\{X \in [1/2,1]\}$.  Then $P[A \cap B] = P[X=1/2]=0$.  PS:  I see that you have edited to give the correct definition of "mutually exclusive."

Answer (score 1):

To have $A \cap B = A$ we must have that $A$ is a subset of $B$, and we write $A \subset B$ or $A \subseteq B$ In probability, this will mean than whenever $A$ happens, $B$ also happens.

Comment: So there isn't a term to describe this?

Comment: You can use subset, you can use if $A$ then $B$, you can say $A$ entails $B$.

Comment: Oooh, "entails" is good.